# Rails 4 Bootstrap Doesn't Load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm really at a breaking point so I hope someone can help me here.

I have followed this documentation (as well as 8 tutorials) https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails

After doing this and attempting to add a navbar from the components/examples pages on the getbootstrap website to my appliaction.html.erb file I do see the text load on my page but I never get any CSS applied to the page.

It's simply not working and I'm at my wits end trying to figure it out.

**UPDATE**

I have https://github.com/KR0SIV/learning-bootstrap

Application.css.scss

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Then just to see if it would work I simply added the Nav bar from the examples to my projects application.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>LearningBootstrap</title>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can do the simple and easy way, with no configurations or gems needed:
 1. Download the files from its [official page](http://getbootstrap.com)
 2. Copy the file `bootstrap.css` and paste it in `app/assets/stylesheets`, also `bootstrap.js` to `app/assets/javascripts` and any other file you want. 
 3. Therefore, you'll be able to use bootstrap wherever in your views and will work perfectly.
Let me know if this works  for you.

Comment: without seeing how you have installed and configured Bootstrap in your application, we cannot help you.

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested and I imported the files into application.css.scss 

although I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: I recommend you to use https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.

Comment: All kinds of trouble getting things to work right with your link Emu.

Is this because I'm doing this on x64 win7?
Would life be easier if I just ran a virtual machine in linux?

Comment: You should post your `application.scss` at the very least and are you specifically trying to use Bootstrap 4 Alpha?

Comment: I have updated my original post with the requested file and them some.

I was trying to use the bootstrap gem, then tried bootstrap-ssas then I tried twitter-bootstrap-rails and had the same result with each of them except the twitter gem actually generated the css files.

The app is fresh and used purely so I can try and figure out bootstrap.
I did try the alpha version at one point today but that also ended with the same result/no css loading.

Comment: Your `application.html.erb` is missing the asset tags to call your CSS and JS files into the views. Search for [Asset Tag Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html). `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`
  `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`

Comment: @vanburen, I added the missing asset tags you mentioned and I'm now running into the following error: Sass::SyntaxError at /blogs
Undefined variable: "$alert-padding".

I did a bit of searching but I'm still not quite sure what is going on here, I'm thinking something along the lines of that variable is likey in the css sheet and so ruby is wondering where this variable is?

Comment: Is this a open source project? If yes please add the Repo URL for inspection.

Comment: Which Bootstrap GEM did you end up using? And this variable comes from [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_alerts.scss)

Comment: @Tobias I just pushed it here is the link: https://github.com/KR0SIV/learning-bootstrap

It's just a quick scaffolded app I setup purely to mess around with bootstrap.

Comment: @vanburen I'm currently using "twitter-bootstrap-rails".
Thank you for pointing out the variable location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all. You have multiple **application** stylesheets in your project. **application.css** and **application.css.scss**. Remove the **application.css** and rename the other one into **application.scss**.

Than remove the following lines:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

The [Bootstrap gem README](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) writes:

> Then, remove all the *= require and *= require_tree statements from
>   the Sass file. Instead, use @import to import Sass files.
>
> Do not use *= require in Sass or your other stylesheets will not be
>   able to access the Bootstrap mixins and variables.

And this is probably your problem here since you said that it didn't find a sass variable.

To import all your other CSS files, add the following line blow the bootstrap imports:

```
@import '**/*';
```

This will add all CSS files recursively.

Of course do you have to add the stylesheet to your HTML template.

Just use the default one of Rails:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

**Important!** Bootstrap 4 is still in development and currently just an Alpha version. I would recommend you to use [Bootstrap 3](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) for production apps. But if it's just for learning it's perfectly fine.

And I wouldn't recommend you to use third-party gems like [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) if there are official gems available.

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed it.

Now I can finally dig into it.